# Firebase data not showing in firebase console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

The firebase data of my custom events(not using the firebase basic events) are not showing on the firebase console although only the event name is showing in the events tab but not displaying any custom parameter name and value of that event. I have also read somewhere that I need to add custom dimensions for it inside the firebase console but how can we do it and what should be exactly placed inside there as the dimensions look a lot more different than the events.
Any help, please.

Comment: Could you share some code of what you are doing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Custom Dimension if you are sending string value for parameter or Custom Metric if you are sending int value.

On the Left side of your console, Go to Custom Definitions, Create a Custom Dimension or Metric according to your need. Provide the information:

- Dimension name: This can be any name. It will appear in the event data. So make sure it is related to parameter name.
- Scope: It can be set to Event or User(Property). In your case, It should be Event.
- Description: This can be anything. It is for you own need.
- Event parameter: The value you pass in your script for the name of parameter. If the dropdown does not contain the parameter name you want, just type the same from the script. Once the parameter is logged, it will work.
- Unit of measurement(Metric only): Select the unit you want for your metric to display in Analytics.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad Hamza Tahir, may Allah bless you with happiness, i have added into the custom dimensions, now waiting for 48 hours so that i can see the performance. Jazakallah.

Comment: Great. Let me know when it show :)